# Aeson fromJSON instance

Tags: json, haskell

I have the following data type:

```
 data User = User { name :: T.Text, bookCount :: Int ,memberSince :: DateTime ,
  email :: T.Text, password :: B.ByteString } 
  | UnverifiedUser { nameUnverified :: T.Text,   emailUnverified :: T.Text,
     secret :: Integer  }
```

And the following instance:

```
instance FromJSON User where
    parseJSON (Object o) | Just _ <- M.lookup "secret" o = UnverifiedUser <$> o .: "name" <*> o .: "email" <*> o .: "secret"
                         | otherwise = User <$>  o .: "name" <*>  o .: "bookCount" <*> o .: "memberSince" <*> o .: "email" <*> o .: "password"
    parseJSON _          = mzero
```

But User was split into two, because sometimes the document in couchdb does not have some fields like secret, or password.
How could I make an fromJSON instance for the data type:

```
   data User = User { name :: T.Text, bookCount :: Int ,memberSince :: DateTime ,
      email :: T.Text, password :: B.ByteString , secret :: Integer  }
```

where some fields are mandatory and others are not ?

Comment: Did you know that different constructors for the same data type can share record field names (provided they also share record field types)? For your example, you could write `data User = Verified { name :: T.Text, email :: T.Text, ... } | Unverified { name :: T.Text, email :: T.Text }`.

Comment: @Daniel: While that is correct, it is often easier to have the common stuff in one data type and split out the different stuff into another: `data User = User { name :: T.Text, email :: T.Text, verification :: Verification }` with `data Verification = Unverified { secret :: Integer } | Verified { memberSince :: DateTime, password :: T.Text }`.

Comment: @Daniel, no I did not. But i do not trust the unverified user enough to accept his name as verified.

Comment: @Hai I'm not sure I understand the connection between trust and how the data type is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `Maybe`?

```
 data User =
   User {
     name            :: T.Text,
     bookCount       :: Int ,
     memberSince     :: DateTime ,
     email           :: T.Text,
     password        :: Maybe B.ByteString,
     nameUnverified  :: T.Text,
     emailUnverified :: T.Text,
     secret          :: Maybe Integer}

instance FromJSON User where
    parseJSON (Object o) = User <$>
         o .: "name"            <*>
         o .: "bookCount"       <*>
         o .: "memberSince"     <*>
         o .: "email"           <*>
         o .:? "password"       <*>
         o .: "nameUnverified"  <*>
         o .: "emailUnverified" <*>
         o .:? "secret"
```

Comment: I ended up doing something a bit different, but using maybe anyway.